# If I attach two leads at the edge of a quantum hall system, can I get the current without adding voltage difference between the two leads?

Tags: electrostatics, quantum-hall-effect, chirality

In a 2-dimension quantum hall system, there always exist the chiral edge state in one edge. The current of the edge state is always in one direction, e.g  $v_x>0$. In this case, if I attach a device to measure the current at one edge, I should always get the current even though I haven't add a votage at the edge. Does that mean I can always get a current without introducing any the electric field ?